# How to add FXML-styled GridPane to pagination in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, pagination, javafx-8, fxml, gridpane

I am currently working on a project that requires me to apply multiple GridPanes to a pagination in JavaFX 8. I already have a GridPane attached to a VBox, in which were styled in SceneBuilder. My question is, how can I basically make multiple copies of this FXML-styled GridPane to each pagination?

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u3yu.png)

[How my layout is layered in SceneBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3wC0.png)

Comment: The [JavaFX documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/pagination.htm#CACJCAGB) demonstrates how to create a page with a VBox layout.  Using GridPane instead of VBox is really no different.

Comment: Thanks! Working through some errors, but that put me back on track!